# jsonschema2pojo returns error when try to generate dto's using schema

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, gradle, jsonschema2pojo

There is a application on spring-boot and gradle and need to generate dto's using json schema.
Try to use jsonschema2pojo plugin for do it and took example from [here](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/tree/master/jsonschema2pojo-gradle-plugin) (changed only plugins block used plugins closure instead apply keyword

build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'org.jsonschema2pojo:jsonschema2pojo-gradle-plugin'
        }
    }
    
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'jsonschema2pojo'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
}

group = 'nuclear.bot'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}


jsonSchema2Pojo {
    generateBuilders = false
    usePrimitives = false
    source = files("src/main/json-schema")
    targetDirectory = file("${project.buildDir}/generated-sources/js2p")
    targetPackage = 'crom.tech.api.models'
    propertyWordDelimiters = [] as char[]
    useLongIntegers = false
    useBigIntegers = false
    useDoubleNumbers = true
    useBigDecimals = false
    includeHashcodeAndEquals = true
    includeToString = true
    annotationStyle = 'jackson2'
    customAnnotator = 'org.jsonschema2pojo.NoopAnnotator'
    includeJsr303Annotations = false
    sourceType = 'jsonschema'
    removeOldOutput = true
    outputEncoding = 'UTF-8'
    useJodaDates = false
    useCommonsLang3 = false
    initializeCollections = true
    classNamePrefix = ""
    classNameSuffix = ""
    fileExtensions = [] as String[]
    includeConstructors = true
    serializable = true
    includeAccessors = true
    includeDynamicAccessors = false
}
```

But when I try to nuild project, there is error message:

> Build file 'C:\learn\Nuclear-bot\Nuclear-bot-parsing-processor\build.gradle' line: 12

Plugin [id: 'jsonschema2pojo'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jsonschema2pojo` plugin doesn't support the `plugins` block. The reason is that it is missing a so-called "[marker artifact](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_markers)" on the Gradle Plugin Portal. This is what tells Gradle what actual dependency (here `org.jsonschema2pojo:jsonschema2pojo-gradle-plugin`) to use for a given plugin. It is also the reason why it isn't listed in the [Portal](https://plugins.gradle.org/).

So we are stuck with the legacy way of applying the plugin for now. There is an issue for it [here](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/issues/282). But as it has been open since 2015, they are probably looking for contributors.

Also note that you need to add a version number to the classpath dependency, e.g.:

```
// Groovy DSL
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.jsonschema2pojo:jsonschema2pojo-gradle-plugin:1.1.2' // <-- Version here
    }
}

plugins {
    // Other plugins here...
}

apply plugin: 'jsonschema2pojo' // <-- Legacy (but required) way of applying the plugin
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was getting no output from the `jsonschema2pojo` plugin because my input was a `JSON` example file and not a `JSON Schema` as is the default, so I needed to add the `setSourceType` parameter.

So my actual `build.gradle.kts` looks like this :

```
plugins {
    java
    id("jsonschema2pojo") version "1.2.1"
}

jsonSchema2Pojo{
    setSourceType("json")
    setSource(files("$projectDir/src/main/resources/json"))
    targetDirectory = file("$buildDir/generated/sources/js2p")
    targetPackage = "com.yourcorp.yourproject.pojo"
    generateBuilders = true
    dateTimeType = "java.time.ZonedDateTime"
    includeAdditionalProperties = false
    setAnnotationStyle("none")
}
```